# asp:RangeValidator MinimumValue > 0

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

I am back at last and actually have a perm job thanks to all the help you guys gave me a while back !! :) Thanks.

Ok, so now I have a simple task, to add some ranges to an existing ASP.Net page.

I am using asp:RangeValidator and have a type=double and want to have a value of > 0 and not >=. Is there a quick and nice way of doing this ??

I know there is a RangeBoundry type in the RangeValidatorAttribute class. Is there something similar I can use in the RangeValidator class at all ?

Many thanks, George.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used MinimumValue and MaximumValue parameters for this.